# Ruby on Rails and Javascript confirm popups in Safari 12

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari

In my Rails apps I have a lot of links like this one:

```
link_to "Destroy", project_path, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }
```

The `confirm` data attribute used to trigger a Javascript popup (and still does in most browsers).

In Safari 12 these popups no longer seem to work, however.

Instead of the actual popup I get the spinning pinwheel (An error message would have been helpful here, Apple!). No errors are reported in my browser console or Rails logs either.

How can this be fixed?

P.S.: My Rails version is 5.1.4

Comment: Just to make sure whether the javascript is running or not try changing it to `link_to "Destroy", project_path, :method => :delete, :onclick=> "return confirm('Are you sure?')" }`

Comment: I just changed it but that didn't fix it. The error persists.

Comment: Not sure did you  see this apple care respond with similar problem "Is Javascript enabled in Safari-Preferences-Security ? 

it's also worth Quitting Safari & trashing the file com.apple.safari.plist which can be found in Home/Library/Preferences/ where Home is your user folder. 
Failing that - try using Safari in another user account - you can create a new one by clicking the + button in System Preferences-Accounts. 
It's also worth trying http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm & clicking the 'Display a confirm box'  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/608595

Comment: Do you have any pop up blocker activated in safari?

Comment: @AnandJose: Yes, I did. But I deinstalled and removed it before posting the question above. My fear is that some of the remnants may have survived, though.

Comment: @Tintin81 Does it work locally? Had the same issue just the other day, locally with non-precompiled assets it was fine. On live server it was failing. Recompiling assets helped here

Comment: @TomD: No, it's actually the exact opposite here. It works in production mode on the server but doesn't work locally. I still haven't found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded and installed the [Safari 12.0.1 developer preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) and that *seems* to have fixed it.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong. The issue keeps creeping back. And I have no idea why. I haven't updated Safari since my last post.

Comment: I just restarted my MacBook Pro and now it's all back to normal. No idea why. I've been struggling with this issue for a month now.

Comment: I also have this problem, and as you said it's intermittent. When it happens the develop "open web inspector" link is grayed out so I can't see any errors. Thought it was a rails-ujs problem but happen with either rails-ujs or jQuery_ujs library. Closing the safari window and opening a new one will get rid of it, for a while. just can't find a sequence that is reproducible. Filed bug report with webkit but no help without a reproducible sequence. Didn't have problem until I switched to Mojave and 12.0.1

Comment: Once you get the problem in a safari window (not tab but window), it is there until you close the window. If you go to the link in Nezri comment [link](http://(w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm ) it will also fail, so it's not your or my code. It's something in Safari.

Comment: Once you get the error condition when destroy links are unresponsive, that safari window is toast (not tab, but window) if you go to the w3school link reference above, the confirm button will also not work, so it's not yours or my code. Close and open the window and it will be ok, for a while! https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

Comment: Yeah, still struggling with this also... My version of Safari (12.0.1) behaves exactly as you describe it.

Comment: I did find a reproducible sequence and webkit [bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191835) reopened my bug. Go to the w3school.com link and click on the tryit! button and select an option. Open another page (bookmark or something), Use back arrow to go back to w3school page and the window will be toast. The confirm link will no longer work.

Comment: @appleII717: Yap, I can confirm this. The confirm link no longer works.